# Convert a Result Set from SQL Array to Array of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, jdbc, resultset

I am querying the `information_schema.columns` table in my PostgreSQL database. Using a table name, the result set finds all the column names, type, and whether it is nullable (except for the primary key, 'id'). This is the query being used:

```
SELECT column_name, is_nullable,data_type FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE lower(table_name) = lower('TABLE1') AND column_name != 'id'
ORDER BY ordinal_position;
```

I have a string array for each of these results and I am trying to use the ResultSet method [`getArray(String columnLabel)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getArray-java.lang.String-) to avoid looping through the results. I want to store the returned Arrays in the string arrays, but get a type mismatch error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Array to String[]
```

Is there a way to convert or typecast the SQL Array object to a String[]?

Relevant Code:

```java
String[] columnName, type, nullable;

//Get Field Names, Type, & Nullability 
String query = "SELECT column_name, is_nullable,data_type FROM information_schema.columns "
        + "WHERE lower(table_name) = lower('"+tableName+"') AND column_name != 'id' "
        + "ORDER BY ordinal_position";

try{
    ResultSet rs = Query.executeQueryWithRS(c, query);
    columnName = rs.getArray(rs.getArray("column_name"));
    type = rs.getArray("data_type");
    nullable = rs.getArray("is_nullable");
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use:

```
Array a = rs.getArray("is_nullable");
String[] nullable = (String[])a.getArray();
```

As explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html)

`Array` is SQL type, `getArray()` returns an object to cast to java array.

Comment: Thank you, I had tried using `rs.getArray("is_nullable").getArray()` but I don't think I had typecast it. This appears to have solved my problem.

Comment: For those who have tried this recently, the `java.sql.Array.getArray()` method now does nothing but throw an `SQLFeatureNotImplemented` exception, so we'll have to find another approach.

Comment: This solution won't work for some drivers, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/55181619/489856

Answer (score 4):

Generalize the Array to Object

```
    Object[] type; //this is generic can use String[] directly
    Array rsArray;

    rsArray = rs.getArray("data_type");
    type = (Object [])rsArray.getArray();
```

Use it loop as string:

```
type[i].toString();
```

Comment: This still causes an error. "_Type mismatch: cannot convert from Array to Object[]_". I think the major problem is that the ResultSet `getArray` method returns a [java.sql Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html), not the java.util.Arrays type under the java.lang Object class. 

Here is the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getArray(java.lang.String)) on the method I'm using.

Comment: @Matt edited and verified, getArray() will return Array, and Array.getArray() returns java array.

Comment: Correct, this would now work, but it requires the unnecessary use of `toString()`. In a case where unknown or a variety of objects are contained in the ResultSet, generalizing to Object[] may be more useful. In my case, I only need Strings.

Answer (score 3):

How to set an ArrayList property from an SQL Array:

```
Array a = rs.getArray("col"); // smallint[] column
if (a != null) {
    yourObject.setListProperty(Arrays.asList((Integer[]) a.getArray()));
}
```

Comment: What is this `o` in line 3?

Comment: o is an instance of an object with a property listProperty of type List<Integer>

Answer (score 1):

**this can be helpful**

```
Object[] balance = (Object[]) ((Array) attributes[29]).getArray();
        for (Object bal : balance) {

            Object [] balObj =(Object[]) ((Array) bal).getArray();
            for(Object obj : balObj){
                Struct s= (Struct)obj;
                if(s != null ){
                    String [] str = (String[]) s.getAttributes();
                    System.out.println(str);
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: I up voted your solution, however please add some description to your answer.