# casting mysql.Array to String[]

Tags: java, mysql

I am using the Java Mysql connector and I have a problem with extracting results:

This is the query and prepared statement that needed to be executed:

```
String statement1 = " select sentence from sentences ; ";
PreparedStatement preparedstatement = conn.prepareStatement(statement1);
ResultSet res = preparedstatement.executeQuery();
```

Now I try to get the results in an array, so I use:

```
Array temp = res.getArray("sentence"); //(1)
String[] temp2 = (String[])temp.getArray();      //(2)
```

(1) returns a mysql.array which contains a locator, which is a logical pointer to the SQL ARRAY on the server, and (2) should do a typecast of temp and return a String[], however I am getting this error

```
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.notImplemented(SQLError.java:1342)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getArray(ResultSetImpl.java:1226)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getArray(ResultSetImpl.java:1243)
    at wikiparse.Wikiparse3.running(Wikiparse3.java:62) // this where I wrote (1) in my java file
    at wikiparse.ActivateWikiparse3.main(ActivateWikiparse3.java:27)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think after exection of `preparedstatement.executeQuery()`, the data is already on your side, rather than server side.

Comment: What is table `sentences` declaration?

Comment: Your code snippet is incomplete, but provided you are calling `res.next()` prior to this call, as the Javadoc states, your JDBC driver doesn't support that.

Comment: as the page you provide `Note: MySQL and Java DB currently do not support the ARRAY SQL data type. Consequently, no JDBC tutorial example is available to demonstrate the Array JDBC data type.`

Comment: @Rugal `In the following statement, the ResultSet method getArray returns the value stored in the column ZIPS of the current row as the java.sql.Array object z:

Array z = rs.getArray("ZIPS");
The variable z contains a locator, which is a logical pointer to the SQL ARRAY on the server; it does not contain the elements of the ARRAY itself. Being a logical pointer, z can be used to manipulate the array on the server.`

Comment: Your failure to read what people are telling you, and the page you link to, is staggering.

Comment: @kolonel but... mysql did not support `array` type...it will not implement it!

Comment: @Rugal There is this post `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935016/convert-a-result-set-from-sql-array-to-array-of-strings`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the documentation the OP links to in the question explains in the first sentence why this will not work with MySQL.

Comment: @kolonel can you see the poster use `postgres` rather than `mysql`?

Comment: so the only way is to iterate over the values?

Comment: @kolonel **What** values?? You can't have an array type in MySQL. You have exactly one value per row.

Comment: @BrianRoach well I  want to iterate over the values in the ResultSet object , I could do that using the getString() method but then I was trying to see if there was a direct way to do it.

Comment: @BrianRoach by direct method I mean a method that does it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should iterate througth the `ResultSet`:

```
List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
String statement1 = " select sentence from sentences  ";
PreparedStatement preparedstatement = conn.prepareStatement(statement1);
try
{
    ResultSet res = preparedstatement.executeQuery();

    while (res.next())
    {
       temp.add(res.getString("sentence"));
    }
}
finally{
    preparedstatement.close();
}
String[] temp2 = temp.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: `ArrayList` doesn't implement or extend `Array`. Did you compile your code?

Comment: This literally makes no sense.

Comment: Excuse-me, but.... why? This code gets all the values from a database table column and stores them in a memory array...

Comment: `Array temp = new ArrayList();` (As ADS pointed out) ? Please, explain. (I think this is just a typo)

Comment: I went ahead and fixed it ;)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't have an ARRAY type, so this method is not implemented.

See http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,160525,160573

Comment: This is from the tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html

Comment: @kolonel Yes, and the *very first sentence* says : "Note: MySQL and Java DB currently do not support the ARRAY SQL data type" ... not to mention because of that you couldn't possibly have that in your table definition.

Comment: @BrianRoach but it says this `In the following statement, the ResultSet method getArray returns the value stored in the column ZIPS of the current row as the java.sql.Array object z:

Array z = rs.getArray("ZIPS");
The variable z contains a locator, which is a logical pointer to the SQL ARRAY on the server; it does not contain the elements of the ARRAY itself. Being a logical pointer, z can be used to manipulate the array on the server.`

Comment: @BrianRoach There is also this post `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935016/convert-a-result-set-from-sql-array-to-array-of-strings`

Comment: Apparently you also don't understand that MySQL and PostgreSQL are completely different databases with different feature sets.

Answer (score 0):

There is [another tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html#retrieve_rs) which shows how to retrieve data from `ResultSet`.

In your case it will be

```
List<String> result = new LinkedList<>();
while (while (rs.next()) {
    result.add(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the extensive comments, you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how a database works, and what the ARRAY type would mean even if MySQL supported it (which it does not).

> well I want to iterate over the values in the ResultSet object , I could do that using the getString() method but then I was trying to see if there was a direct way to do it.

When you query a database, it returns a set of rows from your table that match the query. The JDBC represents this as a `ResultSet`. To get all the results for a given column, yes, you have to iterate through the `ResultSet`:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
while (res.next()) {
    myList.add(res.getString("sentence"));
}
```

There's no shortcut method to have the `ResultSet` do this for you and return a `List`

**Edit to add:** The ARRAY type in PostgreSQL (and possibly others) is an entirely different beast. It allows you to store an array of data in a single row and retrieve it that way.  That's what the `getArray()` and the associated `Array` class is for.

Comment: the extensive comments are because I am trying to understand something , I was trying to see if something could be done in a certain way. The code in your answer is what I already have.

Comment: ESP is on the fritz. That little piece of information would have improved your question dramatically; we would have at least immediately understood your confusion. To be clear, you're confusing a datatype (and the methods/classes to access it) available in a database that is not MySQL with a data structure (ResultSet) in Java.

Comment: You need to add a throws clause in your code because unless you do it wont work. It seems you have a fundamental misunderstanding on how the ResultSet class works.

Comment: Troll harder. That was weak.

Comment: I'm not a troll, never.