# How to cast a Java class instance to Object[] in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I am using a JDBC library that implements its own Array class. In order to work with said Array they cast it to Object[].

https://github.com/housepower/ClickHouse-Native-JDBC/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/housepower/jdbc/QueryComplexTypeITest.java#L120

I am using Clojure and can't figure out how to cast that class to the Java Array.

```
(vec (.getArray results "array-row"))
Unable to convert: class com.github.housepower.jdbc.ClickHouseArray to Object[]
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14935150/3000206) suggests that you'd need to do something like `(into-array String (.getArray (.getArray results "array-row")))`. Note the second call to `.getArray`, and then the "cast" via `into-array`. I'd post an answer, but I can't test this.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that Java code is calling the `.getArray` method, and casting the results to an `Object[]` array, not the other way around? Looking at the source of `com.github.housepower.jdbc.ClickHouseArray` it seems to extend `java.sql.Array` via `com.github.housepower.jdbc.wrapper.SQLArray` which is not an `Object[]`. Right?

Clojure will just do runtime reflection to resolve a method on an object so you shouldn't need to worry about casting. There might be more information in the exception you're getting? Try using `*e` to get at the last exception in the REPL. If you could post a more complete test case, we might get a better idea of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can try to iterate that array and compose the result manually:

```
(let [array (.getArray results "array-row")]
  (for [item array]
    (turn-item-into-a-map item)))
```

or maybe just

```
(mapv turn-item-into-a-map jdbc-array)
```

In case you don't want to convert items, use `identity` function.

Even if such an array doesn't support iteration, you still can do that accessing its items by an index in loop/recur:

```
(let [array (get-jdbc-array...)
      size (.count array)]
  (loop [i 0
         result []]
    (if (= i size)
      result
      (let [item (.get array i)]
        (recur (inc i) (conj result item))))))
```