# Can not extract Double[] from resultset

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have an exception when I try to get array form resultset.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.

Column is generated with hibernate ddl-auto as bytea.
Data like [0.5, 0.02, 0.1] is stored in this column

I try to get data with help of resultSet.getArray("vector").getArray().
There is no exception when I call just resultSet.getArray("vector"), but i get here something like \x5b312c322c335d

```java
class Vector {
   @Column
   private Double[] vector
}


stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT vector FROM vectors");
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
while (resultSet.next()) {
   resultSet.getArray("vector").getArray(); //exception when i do last getArray()
}
```

Comment: What is unclear about "No results were returned by the query."?

Comment: If I execute same query in db console I get all data

Comment: Try `Array rawArr = resultSet.getArray("vector"); Double[] dblArray = (Double[]) rawArray.getArray();` as explained in [the accepted answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935016/convert-a-result-set-from-sql-array-to-array-of-strings). It may not work anymore, see the comment there. Worth a try, I think...

Comment: It isn't working( 
rawArray.getArray() produces exception and it's strange because i'm sure, there is data

Comment: [Another option from the JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html#getArray(java.util.Map)): Provide a type mapping... Sounds awful, but maybe works as desired. This must be supported by the driver you are using, which one is it?

Comment: org.postgresql.Driver
It seems it's not working
resultSet.getArray("vector").getArray(ImmutableMap.of("bytea", Double.class))
Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray.getArrayImpl(long,int,Map) is not yet implemented.